# A question on countable additivity on a ring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would be grateful if someone could help me understand a part of the proof concerning the extension of a measure on a semi-ring $S$ to the right generated by it. Specifically, I do not understand why we can write each $U_{l}$ as a disjoint union of $S_j$s, it would seem to me that we can only write them as a disjoint union of the intersections $\left( U_{i} \cap S_j \right)$.

[image]

I need to clarify that $S_{\cup}$ is the family of all finite disjoint unions of the elements of the semi-ring $S$ and $\cup$ with the dot refers to a disjoint union. If anything else is missing, please let me know.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You choose the $S_j$ so that either $S_j \subset U_i$ or $S_j \cap U_i = \varnothing$. Note that $T_k = (T_k \cap U_1) \cup \dotsc \cup (T_k \cap U_N)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've missed that, would you like to upgrade your comment to a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must choose the $S_j$ appropriately. To do that, start with a decomposition

$$T = U_1 \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} U_2 \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} \dotsc \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} U_N,$$

and then look at the corresponding decomposition of each $T_k$,

$$T_k = (T_k \cap U_1) \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} \dotsc \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} (T_k \cap U_N).$$

Each of the $T_k \cap U_i$ is the disjoint union of finitely many $S_j \in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.